# jsFiddle framework not working

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem, the button of the page is working fine
  http://jsfiddle.net/kommandoss/YuRpU/11/

hovewer I do not have controls over the images and do have contol I have to change the framework to - onLoad - now I can drag images but the button is not working

any ideas what I can do for both to work?? thank you

Comment: We're in 2012, don't use `onclick` attributes, bind your handlers using `$(...).click()` or similar things.

Comment: I removed the onclick inline handler and the `ready` function inside `codeToRun`. [http://jsfiddle.net/CCtZU/](http://jsfiddle.net/CCtZU/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/YuRpU/13/ use live click

Comment: `live` is deprecated. use `on` instead.

Comment: Both drag and the button arent working at the same time, any help please??